# Why do I get the error 'Method execute in android.os.AsyncTask not mocked'

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I'm writing an Android app which needs to listen for UDP broadcast msgs.

I'm trying to mock the AsyncTask in a listener class so I can unit test it.

The problem is I always get the error 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method execute in android.os.AsyncTask not mocked.

```
public class DiscoveryListener
{
    WorkGroupEventHandler workGroupEventHandler;

    private AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> asyncTask;
    private boolean listener_active = false;

    public boolean GetListener_active()
    {
        return listener_active;
    }

    public DiscoveryListener(WorkGroupEventHandler eventHandler)
    {
        workGroupEventHandler = eventHandler;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        if (listener_active == false)
        {
            listener_active = true;
            RunUdpListener();
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        listener_active = false;
        asyncTask.cancel(true);
    }

    public void RunUdpListener()
    {
        asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>()
        {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            byte[] msg = new byte[4096];
            DatagramPacket datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(msg, msg.length);
            MulticastSocket multicastReceiveSocket = null;

            try
            {
                multicastReceiveSocket = new MulticastSocket( 60000 );

                while (listener_active)
                {
                    if (isCancelled() == false)
                    {
                        multicastReceiveSocket.receive(datagramPacket);
                        ProcessIncommingMessage(datagramPacket.getAddress(), msg);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (multicastReceiveSocket != null)
                {
                    multicastReceiveSocket.close();
                }
            }

            return null;
            }
        };

        asyncTask.execute();
    }
}


@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({android.util.Log.class, android.os.AsyncTask.class})
public class DiscoveryListenerUnitTest
{
    private WorkGroupEventHandler eventHandler = new WorkGroupEventHandler()
    {
        @Override
        public void onWorkGroupEventHandle(String IpAddress, String Workgroup, String SerialNumber)
        {
        }
    };

    private DiscoveryListener discoveryListener = new DiscoveryListener(eventHandler);
    private AsyncTask asyncTask;

    @Test
    public void discoveryListener_doesStart() throws Exception
    {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(android.util.Log.class);

        PowerMockito.whenNew(AsyncTask.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(asyncTask);
        asyncTask = PowerMockito.mock(AsyncTask.class);
        when(asyncTask.execute()).thenReturn(null);

        discoveryListener.Start();
        assertEquals(true, discoveryListener.GetListener_active());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

AsyncTask.execute is final, and Mockito can't mock final classes or methods.

```
    Cannot mock final methods - their real behavior is executed without any exception. Mockito cannot warn you about mocking final methods so be vigilant.
```

Specifically, this is because Java can resolve the link at compile time, which means Mockito can't use its generated subclasses and method overrides to change the behavior.

You may choose to use Powermock, which uses a special classloader to rewrite the old behavior, or Robolectric, which does the same but replaces classes with Android-specific test-friendly alternate implementations ("shadows") including one for AsyncTask.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I thought I was using PowerMock by making the call asyncTask = PowerMockito.mock(AsyncTask.class); Can you give an example of how I would use PowerMock?